# Cannot retrieve MethodInfo from rhino mocked interface during testing

Tags: c#, reflection, mocking, rhino

I'm presently working on a project that includes tests with *RhinoMocks* mocked objects. Since upgrading to *RhinoMocks 3.6.1* from *3.6.0* previously working project code is failing during testing. The issue seems to be caused by changed behavior of mock objects between versions. The generated Mock objects are now Castle Proxy objects that don't appear to be reflectable. Previously it was possible to gather MethodInfo from a mocked object via reflection, which no longer seems to be the case. Should I be setting up my mocks in a different way?

A greatly simplified example follows:

Given an interface to be mocked

```
public interface IValidator<in T>
{
    bool Validate(T obj);
}
```

in testing code the mock is created with an expectation:

```
var validator = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IValidator<string>>();
validator.Expect(v => v.Validate(Arg<string>.Is.Equal("input")))
    .Return(true);
...
// the validator object is then passed into a consumer and assertions 
// are checked to be sure the consumer and validator appropriately 
// behave (outside scope of question)
```

Within the consumer class reflection is done to get the "Validate" method from the interface in order to be invoked during standard execution:

```
var method = validator.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

The crux of the issue is `method` is now null when using the update version of *RhinoMocks* as reflection no longer seems to work.

The root of my issue is the inability to reflect on the proxy object generated by Rhino / Castle when all I have are instances an no ability to do explicit casting.

Comment: How can you expect a mock to be created with a `Result` method if there's no `Result` method in the interface? It doesn't seem to be related to a new RhinoMocks version.

Comment: Good catch @tzachs, it was a copy/paste error on my part when simplifying. Corrected.

Comment: Why do you need reflection in the first place? Why can't you just call `validator.Validate`? Something to do with generics? Sounds like you might be able to design a better solution.

Comment: @tzachs the example I provided is very simplified to the point of just exercising the issue at hand. The over arching solution is highly generic and significantly more complex and does require reflection in order to operate. Worth mentioning the solution does work, but the testing harness no longer appears to be operating as it did in previous versions of RhinoMocks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might get me punched in the face.
But if you are in a generic class you could quite easily do something like

```
var method = typeof(IValidator<T>).GetType()
    .GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Also if the project is very large and there are alot of tests and mocks, this may be a huge amount of rework :(

**EDIT:**
Ok round 2 :)

The problem seems to be in the fact that the mock is a dynamic class and does not actually seem to have that method.

How about instead of using GetMethod you create an interface (ITypeHelper) that has a number of wrapper methods for getting types and methods.

Normally these would just call the methods directly (so as to not cause any perfomance penalties), but during testing you could swap out your implementation of ITypeHelper for a MockTypeHelper (by changing the registration in the container or some other mechanisim).

```
public class RhinoMocks_33901386
{
    //public static ITypeHelper TypeHelper = new TypeHelper();
    //use when testing
    public static ITypeHelper TypeHelper = new MockTypeHelper();

    public static void Run()
    {
        var validator = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IValidator<string>>();
        validator.Expect(v => v.Validate(Arg<string>.Is.Equal("input"))).Return(true);

        var method = TypeHelper.GetMethod(validator.GetType(), "Validate");

        var result = (bool) method.Invoke(validator, new object[] {"input"});
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IValidator<in T>
{
     bool Validate(T obj);
}

public interface ITypeHelper
{
    MethodInfo GetMethod(Type self, string name);
}

public class TypeHelper : ITypeHelper
{
    public virtual MethodInfo GetMethod(Type self, string name)
    {
        return self.GetMethod(name);
    }
}

public class MockTypeHelper : ITypeHelper
{
    public virtual MethodInfo GetMethod(Type self, string name)
    {
        if (typeof(IMockedObject).IsAssignableFrom(self) && self.BaseType == typeof(object))
        {
            self = self.GetInterfaces()
                .First(x => x != typeof(IMockedObject) && x != typeof(ISerializable) && x != typeof(IProxyTargetAccessor));
        }

        return self.GetMethod(name);
    }
}
```

Hope I'm getting warmer ;p

Comment: in the simplified example I provide depending on the consumer's implementation your answer may be correct. However, in the actual implementation of the consumer I'm dealing with I don't have access to the generic parameter T (and shouldn't), only it's type information. Your answer unfortunately doesn't satisfy the root issue of the inability to reflect on the proxy object generated by Rhino / Castle.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your most recent edit looks like I'd be testing the MockTypeHelper interaction with the consumer rather than verifying call state of the validator with the consumer. The current iteration of executed code is succinct and functional, it seems inappropriate to add such harnesses purely for the sake of testing. If anything creating an explicit non mocked validator class specific for testing would be the better option. What I was looking for was how to setup RhinoMocks to create the same or similar interaction of proxies as was default in the previous minor version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like RihnoMocks or Castle DynamicProxy has changed how it works internally. As @sQuir3l pointed out, it seems to be using dynamic objects internally.

In this particular case you can work around the change by accessing the underlying interface type like this:

```
var method = ((IMockedObject)validator).ImplementedTypes
    .Single(type => type == typeof(IValidator<string>))
    .GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it ends up modifying code to know that it is under test. Eg special actions to happen only when testing occurs, and will in essence only validate the testing harness. Such things are generally considered code smell. It is very possible that RhinoMocks has been changed in a way that it is no longer compatible with previous testing paradigms. I'm looking for Rhino configuration change or or a verification that it was purposeful change.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way of changing the behavior. You will probably need to try another IOC container or do an old fashioned fake to work around this.